# Prevent Visual Studio's "Home" page when Pressing the Web Home key

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I search the web a lot when writing code. When working in Visual Studio 2008, every time I hit the keyboard's <kbd>Web Home</kbd> key (you know the one on every multi media keyboard with the house on it) it opens a browser *in VisualStudio* - usually to something on MSDN.

Not that I don't like MSDN, but I'd like to open a real browser on my second monitor and go to *my home page*. Is there a way to tell Visual Studio not to open it's own home page and instead let Windows process it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bypass Visual Studio processing this key by means of the excellent free utility [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It can help with all sorts of automation needs, but in particular [Overriding or Disabling Hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm) of course, see the list of [Hotkeys (Mouse, Joystick and Keyboard Shortcuts)](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) too.

Your scenario requires [Context-sensitive Hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Context); the necessary parameters to discriminate target applications via Window class and/or title can be determined via the included *Window Spy* utility.

While I'm working on a laptop right now, which doesn't feature a *Browser Home* key, I just tested the following script fragment successfully with another keyboard shortcut:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class wndclass_desked_gsk ; Visual Studio browser home key hook
Browser_Home::Run firefox.exe http://example.com
#IfWinActive ; Subsequent mappings/hotkeys in effect for all windows again now
```

I usually start one keyboard shortcut related script (incidentally called `Windowskey.ahk`) automatically via my user `Start Menu\Programs\Startup` folder, and launch other scripts from there via a hotkey as needed ;)

Comment: It's a bummer you can't do it without an external tool but - this worked!! Plus now I'm really looking at AutoHotkey a bit more...it's been on my radar and now I'll give it some more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Is there not a way in the visual studio shortcuts to disable the home button?

Answer (score 0):

Does it do that when Visual Studio is not open?  If so, check your [file associations](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859).

Answer (score 0):

Did your keyboard have an utility to associate the key? Maybe launching the browser directly will avoid your problem

Answer (score 0):

Tools/Options

Environment/Keyboard

In the list, Find View/Home, and assign it to a very complex shortcut keys combination.
Also do the same for View/StartPage and View/WebBrowser

Comment: Clever idea, but does not work - at least I now have two ways to open the page I never ever use :)

Comment: What about set a custom action in Visual Studio that launches your browser, and attached to your "Home key"?

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard shortcuts for the multimedia keys can be customized using something like TweakUI. I think you'd have to modify the Home action for the keyboard, not a Visual Studio shortcut.

Comment: Yes, the home key can be redirected to something else - even with simple tools like SharpKeys. The problem however with that is it breaks the home key when I'm not using VS. I want the home key to go to _my_ home. Not VS.NET. I just want VS to ignore it.